# Bind command on ADB to Android Emulator problem

Tags: adb, android-emulator, command-line, bind-mount

im sorry.. im new here.. i don't know where to start. i want to run some command in emulator (android). im running certain apps, and i need it to run and not to be detectable in emulator instead as android mobile. The problem is, this command suppose to bind certain file, but its not bind.. maybe the bind command is wrong. see below script/command

```
@echo off

adb.exe kill-server
adb.exe start-server
adb.exe devices
adb root
adb remount

adb shell sleep 2

adb shell am start com.abc.im /com.abcgames.ab1.SplashActivity filter

adb shell sleep 3
adb shell pidof com.abc.im

adb shell sleep 6
adb shell for i in $(pidof com.abc.im | awk '{print $1}'); do mount --bind /proc/2/maps /proc/$i/maps; done
```

above if full command that i write on batch file (*.bat)

my question is in this particular command below

```
for i in $(pidof com.abc.im | awk '{print $1}'); do mount --bind /proc/2/maps /proc/$i/maps; done
```

its not working. can anybody help me correct it?

p.s - sory for my poor english...  TQ

Comment: Are you sure all those commands really finished successfully? `adb root` and `adb remount` require a rooted device/emulator with a special adb version installed. Therefore usually on recent device/emulators these commands will fail.

Comment: yes. its rooted emulator. is the bind command right? i suspect the command is missing something or syntax wrong or else.. can help me?

Comment: is this command right?

**`for i in $(pidof com.abc.ig) | awk '{print $1}' | do mount --bind /$i /proc/$i/maps; done`**